# 3d packet choice

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am going to draw approximately 150 drawings like this (in the sense of the level of difficulty) or a little bit easier.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
That is the package choice is important.

I have all these images made in Cabri3D. Is there any way to convert *cg3 Cabri files (or *.eps or *.png, that it produce) into something closer to tikz3d or something like that. I want that the final drawings look like this.
[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated. I need a packet that has a manual with good amount of examples. Tikz3d?

Comment: why do you need tikz (or pstricks) rather than just import the images that you make in the existing application?

Comment: I need it because of several reasons:

1. Cabri doesn't provide vector graphics

2. I also need name the points and they have to be of the same size and font as in text. Cabri doesn't provide it.
3. The drawings shoud look like and match the drawings in the second (2D) part of my book where I used tikz-euclide (actually the last picture if from the second 2D part). 4. The book will be black and white, I need that kind of esthetics.

Comment: You said you could export to `.eps`. It is a vector format. For the fonts, `psfrag` or `psfrags` allows you to substitute text in .eps figures with latex tex.

Comment: Right!  But I have converted png to eps using I don't remember what. So technically it is non-vector graphics in vector format. And it is visible while scaling.

Comment: May be Asymptote would be good for this. You can get raster images with as much detail as you want (which equals vector graphics in print); and possibly vector graphics.

Comment: Possibly an irritating question, but why did you prepare them in Cabri if the results are so unsuitable for your purposes? This seems like a strange choice! Also, if you only have raster, conversion can't make it as if it was originally vector. Your experiments with conversion to EPS already told you this.

Comment: cfr, I made them in Cabri when I was stupid and didn't even anticipated the Asymptote existence. Now I have ended up with Asymptote. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: You have to use an `@` to ping. Just writing the name doesn't do it. Anyway, that all makes sense now. I can totally understand the 'I didn't know then ... ' (or didn't think then or never imagined etc.). That's just life, I guess. Or human life, anyway. Or so it seems to me. Of course, I think this now, but later ...